# Initialize a list of map using ConfigurationProperties in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am looking for a neat way to initialize a List of Maps using Spring Boot from application.properties.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail") 
public class ConfigProperties { 
private String hostName;
private int port;
private List<Map<String,String>> userList;  


// standard getters and setters
```

}

I want to initialize the List of Maps "**userList**" from application.properties. How do we give values to mail.userList below in the application.properties file?

```
#application.properties
mail.hostname=host@mail.com
mail.port=9000
mail.userList=?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mail.userList[0]={'key':'value','key1':'value'}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define it like this,

```
mail.userList[0].id=1
mail.userList[0].name=abc
mail.userList[1].id=2
mail.userList[1].name=pqr
mail.userList[2].id=3
mail.userList[2].name=xyz
```

This will load the in the userlist as list of map. Each entry in the list would contain
id and name.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pratap.. let me wait if there are other answers which are bit compact, your solution is good.. Will accept the answer.